# How to print laravel's 5.5's validation response in in axios

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, axios

My code was working on laravel 5.4 and when upgraded it is not working. I then tried to see the returned response object in the network.

This is what I see

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
  errors:{userName: ["The user name has already been taken."], email: ["The 
     email has already been taken."]}
```

In my axios I am trying to console the message "The user name has already been taken" and "The email has already been taken."

But I shows undefined. Here is my code.

```
.catch(function (error) {
       // This shows undefined. 
       console.log(error.errors]);
  });
```

**Full object**

```
{
"message": "The given data was invalid.",
"errors": {
    "userName": [
        "The user name field is required."
    ],
    "email": [
        "Email is required!"
    ],
    "password": [
        "The password field is required."
    ],
    "lastName": [
        "The last name field is required."
    ],
    "userType": [
        "The user type field is required."
    ]
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the response value passed by Axios will have a `data` field which will contain your values. So you code needs to be

```
.catch(function (error) {
   // This shows undefined. 
   console.log(error.data.errors);
});
```

Comment: Is it ` console.log(error.data.errors]);` Because you have a `]`. I used without `]` and gives me `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined` error

Comment: sorry mistype - removed the `]`

Comment: edited the full object returned by laravel. How can I access error message from this object?

Answer (score 1):

Check your response in `.then`, like this

```
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data.errors);
});
```

Comment: Hi, since laravel sends a status code of 422 the response doesn't enter into .then function it has be caught in .catch. So errors are .catch.

Comment: what you get in `console.log(error.errors);` by removing `]` in your code ?

Comment: Undefined. 
 
I edited the full object in my question returned by laravel. How can I access error message from this object?

Comment: I mean just try `.catch(function (error) {
       // This shows undefined. 
       console.log(error.errors);
  });`

Comment: @sadek : where you see this response ? in console ? netwrok tab ?

Comment: I get undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154986/discussion-between-user2486-and-sadek).

Comment: Yes in network and then for a better view I returned the response data in postman. See the edited question if you haven't :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping you all. I solved it with your helps. here is how I did it.

```
 .catch(error => {
     console.log(error.response.data.errors.email[0])
  });
```